# Get value from Person or Group Type field in SPFx

Tags: spfx-webparts, expand, person-or-group

In my Sharepoint list I have one column of person or group type, I want to fetch its value on my webpart. I have even tried using `$expand` to get that column value but still not getting. In  my webpart under that column it is showing `[object Object]`. One thing I observe that this column value is displaying when I am running following rest API link on browser. So in browser I am getting the result but not on my web part.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProposalDetails')/Items?$select=Location,Date1,Event_x0020_ID,Host1/FirstName&$expand=Host1
```

In above rest API url `Host1` column is of `person or group` type, I want value of this column in SPFx web part.

Comment: any answers on this

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProposalDetails')/items?$select=Location,Date1,Event_x0020_ID,Host1/Title&$expand=Host1/Id
```